# Error in creating MySQL table with multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql5

I am trying to create a table with multiple foreign keys , but getting error msg...
Here is the query

```
create table REVIEW (
    REVIEWER_ID varchar(255) not null,
    DOCTOR_ID integer not null,
    REVIEW varchar(255),
    DATE datetime,
    primary key (REVIEWER_ID, DOCTOR_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

 alter table REVIEW 
    add constraint FK_n1a9feqfl96wayocqr6n04p2y 
    foreign key (DOCTOR_ID) 
    references DOCTORS_INFORMATION (DOCTOR_ID)
```

It has executed the upper statement. But when i do the following it is showing error.

```
 alter table REVIEW 
    add constraint FK_fpmwq7vslmp90var2qmw2lhf4 
    foreign key (REVIEWER_ID) 
    references REVIEWER_INFORMATION (REVIEWER_ID)
```

Reviewer_information table was created using the following command

```
create table REVIEWER_INFORMATION (
    REVIEWER_ID integer not null auto_increment,
    EMAIL varchar(255),
    FIRSTNAME varchar(255),
    LASTNAME varchar(255),
    PHONE_NUMBER integer,
    primary key (REVIEWER_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: **Error Code : 1215**
Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Sorry i figured out....REVIEWER_ID in table REVIEW is varchar whereas in REVIEWER_INFORMATION it is integer